# DAM Solutions for full-length movies

Tags: content-management

Are there any DAM (Digital Asset Management) solutions in the market that can handle storage & classification of full length movies (10 GB and greater). 
Have heard of solutions from EMC Documentum, Artesia, Oracle UCM and the like but not sure if they handle file sizes this large ? Any open-source systems ?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go out on a a limb and say 'No'. There may be some custom ones around, but I have not seen anything that could handle videos of that size.

Personally, I have implemented the image portion of Oracle's DAM (still owned by Stellent at the time). I remember the tech being optimized for short streaming videos.

In Aust, ABC recently launched a streaming service;
http://www.abc.net.au/iview/
This, like other I have seen that are similar, seem to be limited to episodes or shows limited to 1/2 or single hour blocks.

Actually, 10gb seems like a crazy size to be entered into a CM system. As CM implies the files will be shared/ available remotely.
Are the videos uncompressed? 
Do you want to stream/provide them across the network?
I would be interested to know some more details on the system you are after.

Comment: Thanks Tyronomo for your response. 
My query was based on a request a friend who works in a movie production house put up one day. That set me thinking - what systems do these movie houses use for digital storage and retrieval of their movie banks (apart from betamax tapes) ?

Comment: Thats a rather interesting situation. I have a friend of a friend that now works for a TV studio. Ill drop him a line at some point and see if knows what they use.